# Как можно сохранить и загрузить UI элемент с сохранением привязок

Tags: wpf, .net

Есть ли какой-то простой способ сохранения контрола (в моем случае Canvas с добавленными на него фигурами), а потом его динамической загрузки?

Comment: Вам это не нужно, храните модель и восстанавливайте контролы из нее

Comment: @АндрейNOP, увы, это нужно кампании, тестовое задание которой я выполняю.

Comment: Как там дословно написано?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, нужно сделать простенький векторный редактор с возможность сохранения и загрузки рабочей области. Рабочую область я сделал в виде Canvas на котором рисуются ломаные линии. Этот самый Canvas я и хочу сохранять.

Comment: Ага, требования сохранять именно контролы нет, значит делайте так как я написал выше

Comment: Подсказка: делая тестовое задание на wpf не реализуя при этом mvvm, вы заведомо обрекаете себя на провал, ибо это общепризнанный стандарт

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я его и использую. Дело в том, что более простого способа сохранить результат в файл я не придумал. 
Вы написали "хранить модель". Можно немного расшифровать?

Comment: Например, у вас должен быть vm-класс "Линия" и какая-то главная vm, в которой будет лежать коллекция этих линий. Вот вам надо как раз сериализовать эту коллекцию линий (или фигур в общем случае). А интерфейс будет с помощью шаблонов и привязок отображаться автоматически. Контролы, естественно, сохранять не надо, это категорически неправильно.

Comment: Сохраняйте рабочие данные в файлах. Эти данные используются для создания vm (не нужно сериализовать vm - они не данные), а контролы отрисуют себя уже по этим vm